# How to automatically upgrade plugin dependencies of a Maven project using versions-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

I have a parent project where I manage dependencies and plugins using `<dependencyManagement>` and `<pluginManagement>` entries:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        ...
```

Using `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates` I can see that one plugin can be upgraded:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] --- versions:2.16.2:display-plugin-updates (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] The following plugin updates are available:
[INFO]   maven-jar-plugin ................................... 3.1.0 -> 3.3.0
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins have a version specified.
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However none of the goals listed at https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html seems to be capable of actually modifying the `pom.xml` accordingly

The `use-latest-versions` goal only seems to consider project dependencies but not plugins.

Is the versions-maven-plugin missing the functionality to auto upgrade plugin versions or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Correct the versions plugin did not have a step for plugins. I have no test env at the moment, but I belief you can define all Plugin versions as maven properties and use versions:update-properties

Comment: Or you use [dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot) or [renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate)

Comment: @khmarbaise I am currently working in an environment where I can neither use dependabot nor renovate.

Comment: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate?tab=readme-ov-file#self-hosting